# How to do model instance in django update views

Tags: django

**views.py**

```py
def visitor(request):
    fruser = FRUser.objects.get(id=1)
    if request.method == "POST":
        fruser.uid = request.POST.get('visitor_nric_no')
        fruser.name = request.POST.get('name')
        fruser.company_name = request.POST.get('company_name')
        fruser.user_type = request.POST.get('userType')
        fruser.visit_purpose = request.POST.get('purposeOfVisit')
        fruser.valid_from_date = request.POST.get('validFrom')
        fruser.valid_till_date = request.POST.get('validTill')
        fruser.save()
        print(fruser.name)
        return render(request,'kiosk/visitor-checkIn/photo-registration.html',{'fruser':fruser})
    else:
        return render(request, 'kiosk/visitor-checkIn/visitor-new-registration.html')
```

**models.py**

```py
class FRUser(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(to=Image, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    frtemplate = models.ForeignKey(to=FRTemplate, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.TextField(null=True)
    user_type = models.TextField(null=True)
    uid = models.TextField(null=True)
    company_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    visit_purpose = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    employee_number = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    designation = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    valid_from_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    valid_till_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    valid_from_time = models.TimeField(null=True)
    valid_till_time = models.TimeField(null=True)
    is_blacklisted = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)    
    is_other_visit_purpose = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)    
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+', null=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+', null=True)
```

**html**

```html
<form id="visitorRegistration" data-bind="submit: save"  method="post" action="/kiosk/visitor/{{fruser.id}}"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text-white float-left pl-3">User Type</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control bord-r form-control-s" value="{{ fruser.user_type }}" disabled="disabled" name="userType">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text-white float-left pl-3">Name <i class="text-danger">*</i></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control bord-r form-control-s" name="name" data-bind="value: name" value="{{ fruser.name }}" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text-white float-left pl-3">NRIC/FIN Number</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control bord-r form-control-s"  name="visitor_nric_no" value="{{ fruser.uid }}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text-white float-left pl-3">Purpose of visit <i class="text-danger">*</i></label>
                <select class="form-control bord-r form-control-s select2" name="purposeOfVisit" value="{{ fruser.visit_purpose }}">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text-white float-left pl-3">Company Name <i class="text-danger">*</i></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control bord-r form-control-s" name="company_name" data-bind="value: company_name" value="{{ fruser.company_name }}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text-white float-left pl-3">Mobile Number <i class="text-danger">*</i></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control bord-r form-control-s" name="mobileNumber">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text-white float-left pl-3">Access Template</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control bord-r form-control-s" disabled="disabled" name="accessTemplate">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text-white float-left pl-3">Valid From</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control bord-r form-control-s" disabled="disabled" name="validFrom">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text-white float-left pl-3">Valid Till</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control bord-r form-control-s" disabled="disabled" name="validTill">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text-white float-left pl-3">Facility <i class="text-danger">*</i></label>
                <select class="form-control bord-r form-control-s facility-row" name="facility"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-12">
            <div class="form-group sector-multiselect-wrp">
                <label class="text-white float-left pl-3">Block <i class="text-danger">*</i></label>
                <select class="form-control bord-r form-control-s multiSelect block" multiple="multiple" name="block">
                    <option>Block1</option>
                    <option>Block2</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-12">
            <div class="form-group text-left">
                <label class="w-100">&nbsp;</label>
                <button type="button" class="btn rounded-circle add-btn"><i class="ion-plus-round"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 text-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn back-btn bord-r">Back</button>
            <button type="submit" data-bind="click: save" class="btn bord-r">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to do update view of this html page
How to get instance of FRUser model I did'nt get how to do this
I need FRUser model instance data in this html page
I need instance name,company_name like that all i need in html page how to do this
When i given id=1, it also not displaying id = 1 data
please help me
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your html, do:

```
{% if fruser %}
    {{fruser.name}}
{% endif %}
```

This should print out the name on the html.

Comment: No it is not printing name

Comment: I think issue is in views I dont know what is the issue..How to do update for this model

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Django Form as it would do this automatically for you

But to fix this specific problem, you need to pass `fruser` to your template `kiosk/visitor-checkIn/visitor-new-registration.html`

You can do this the same way you did for your template `kiosk/visitor-checkIn/photo-registration.html`

```
return render(request, 'kiosk/visitor-checkIn/visitor-new-registration.html', {'fruser':fruser})
```

Comment: It is not working how to do update for this model

Comment: You will have to provide more details, what is not working? Why are you not using a ModelForm and FormView?

Comment: Iam not using forms.py iam using custom form thats why please help me

Comment: Sorry, cannot help without knowing the problem. I do not believe you have a use case for forms that Django does not work with and you should use Django's Forms